# I can't save newly added tasks to localStorage using Context and useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import { fetchTodos } from "../api/fetch";

// Create Context
const TodosContext = createContext();
const TodosDispatchContext = createContext();

// Reducer
function todosReducer(todos, action){
        switch(action.type){
             case "TODOS":
                return [...action.payload];
             case "ADD_TASK":
               return [...todos, action.payload];

             case "DELETE_TASK":
                return  todos.filter((task) => task.id  !== action.payload);
             case "EDIT_TASK": 
                const updatedTaskIndex = todos.findIndex((task) => task.id === action.payload.id);
                const updatedTodos = [...todos];
                      updatedTodos[updatedTaskIndex] = action.payload;
                return updatedTodos;
             case "COMLETED_UNCOMPLETED":
                return todos.map((task) => task.id === action.payload ? {...task, completed: !task.completed} : task);
             case "COMPLETE_ALL_TASKS":
                return todos.map((task) => task && {...task, completed: true});
             case "DELETE_COMPLETE_TASKS":
                return todos.filter((task) => !task.completed);

                default: return todos;
        }
}
const initialState = [];

 const initializer = (initialValue = initialState) =>
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || initialValue;

export function StateProvider ({children}) {
       const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(todosReducer, [], initializer);
       const [taskToEdit, setTaskToEdit] = useState("");
       const [editTaskId, setEditTaskId] = useState(null); 
       const [filteredTask, setFilteredTask] = useState('all');



    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchingTodos = async () => {
        const data = await fetchTodos()

        dispatch({type: "TODOS", payload: data})
    }
    fetchingTodos();
    },[]);

    useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
    },[todos])
  
       return (
            <TodosContext.Provider value={ 
                {todos, setTaskToEdit, taskToEdit,
                 editTaskId, setEditTaskId, filteredTask, setFilteredTask 
                } }>
                <TodosDispatchContext.Provider value={ {dispatch} }>
                         {children}
                </TodosDispatchContext.Provider>
            </TodosContext.Provider>
       )
}
export function useTodosValues() {
    return useContext(TodosContext);
}
export function useTodosDispatch() {
    return useContext(TodosDispatchContext);
};
```

In my StateProvider component, I am utilizing useReducer with a custom initializer function to fetch initial data from localStorage. The initial data is successfully retrieved, and subsequent changes to the state trigger the useEffect to save the updated state to localStorage.

The issue arises when I attempt to add new tasks using the ADD_TASK action. Although the tasks are added successfully to the state, they are inconsistently saved to localStorage. As a result, the newly added tasks are not persisted across page reloads.

I have verified that the fetchTodos function, responsible for fetching initial data, is working correctly. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions regarding why new tasks might not be consistently saved to localStorage.
Thank you for your assistance.